# Редактировать стили одного слова как отдельной части текста

Tags: html, css

Как обратиться к одному слову в тексте,чтобы редактировать его стили отдельно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте обёртку `<span>` к слову. Тег закрывайте, как `</span>`

Comment: исправьте ответ ... что бы  было ясно

Answer (score 5):

Для этого используйте тег [`span`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/span), он для этого и придуман:

```css
div{
  color: green;
}
span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Вот <span>это</span> предложение!</div>
```